# How to populate images from database to html page using html5 and javascript in phonegap application

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am newbie to HTML5 and javascript so please help me  to get out from this problem.

Here i am developing a phonegap application which i can run on android and ios. In my application i have to load the data and images and populate onto html page. So images and information related to that image will be displayed in a list view in html page. But i am not getting how to populate images and data on html page from data base. so please help me to getout from this problem.

My html page should look like this after populating data.

please help me.thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat broad, but in general, you communicate with a remote database using AJAX in the PhoneGap application and an application server that integrates with your database. So for example, you may use ColdFusion, PHP, etc on your server to integrate with your database. You set up code that can respond to HTTP requests and return information, like the paths to those images, as JSON.

In your PhoneGap app than it is a simple matter of requesting those APIs using AJAX.